# Form which i getting from ajax not working in admin panel Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax, admin-panel

I have a form in the content of the ajax response, but when I submit the form, the action does'nt work (redirected to dashboard), form action same page,  but when I use this form without Ajax, then it works fine, thanks for help

```
<form class="wrapper" method="GET" name="go_to_print_page" id="go_to_print_page" action="<?php echo $createAction; ?>">
     <input name="send_customer_id" class="send_customer_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo   $customerId; ?>" />
     <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php  echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
     <button type="submit" class="submit"><?php echo __("View");?></button>
</form>
```

AJAX REQUEST

```
  jQuery.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: "POST",
             data: {createdFrom:createdFrom,createdTo:createdTo},
             showLoader: false,
             cache: false,
             success: function(response){
             jQuery('#printTable_wrapper').html(response.output);
             jQuery('#printTable_wrapper').trigger('contentUpdated');
             });
```

Comment: $createAction how you create this url?

Comment: $createMyAction = $baseUrl.'/cart/printcartinfo/';

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong. Try following way so you can get correct URL for admin action:

```
$block->getUrl('cart/printcartinfo');
```